# SOAP Authentication problems with XML created on google docs script editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to connect (via the script editor from a google spreadsheet) to an API via SOAP & WSDL ( http://wiki.affiliatewindow.com/index.php/Affiliate_service_APIV3 ).

I'm struggling creating the header XML object, which according to the example (from the link above) should have two elements, the 'UserAuthentication' and the 'getQuota'.
If I send the header with only the user authentication I get a server error in response; if I try to send both elements I get an authentication error.

Any help will be much appreciated!

** Update **
The authentication header seems to be working (or at least is not returning any errors); the error I'm now getting is "Procedure 'getTransactionList' not present" (and it should be present).

Here's my code so far:

```
function testSOAP() {
// Affiliate Window API from here
  var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v3/AffiliateService?wsdl");

  var apiService = wsdl.getService( wsdl.getServiceNames() );
  //Logger.log(apiService); // ApiService

  var headerA = [
    "ns1:UserAuthentication",
    { "SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand" : "true" },
    { "SOAP-ENV:actor" : "http://api.affiliatewindow.com" },
    [ "ns1:iId", "******" ],
    [ "ns1:sPassword", "**************************************" ],
    [ "ns1:sType", "affiliate" ]
  ];
  var headerQ = [
    "ns1:getQuota", "true"
  ];

  var paramJ = [
    "ns1:getTransactionList",
    [ "ns1:dStartDate", "2011-08-01T00:00:00" ],
    [ "ns1:dEndDate", "2011-08-30T23:59:59" ],
    [ "ns1:sDateType", "transaction" ]
  ];
  // I read that the paramaters should be sent as an XML element, not JSON (as above)
  // but neither of the formats seem to work
  var paramX = Xml.element("ns1:getTransactionList", [
                           Xml.element("ns1:dStartDate", ["2011-08-01T00:00:00"]),
                           Xml.element("ns1:dEndDate", ["2011-08-30T23:59:59"]),
                           Xml.element("ns1:sDateType", ["transaction"])
  ]);

  // this returns the generated xml that will be sent
  var result = apiService.getSoapEnvelope("getTransactionList", paramX, [headerA, headerQ]);
  Logger.log(result);

  var transL = apiService.getOperation("getTransactionList");
  //Logger.log(transL);

  var env = transL.invokeOperation([paramJ], [headerA, headerQ]);
  Logger.log(env);

  Logger.getLog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the Apps Script Soap Services, but have you tried a single dimension array for the headers? (because you're using a 2-dimension one). e.g.

```
var header = [headerA, headerQ]; //your snippet had "extra" brackets

var result = apiService.invokeOperation("getTransactionList", [param], header);
Logger.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I've tried that and it returns a 'Could not parse text' error.